# How to show month prior the end date the user has chosen in Webi 4.1

Tags: charts, linechart, business-objects, webix

I'm creating a dashboard in Webi 4.1. When I run the prompt I choose the start and end dates for the report. However, I have a line chart that shows the volume trend by month over time and I want it to exclude the end date and instead show the month right before that.

Example: I choose June 1 2016 as the start date and June 14 2017 (today's current date) as the end date. However for the line graph I want it to show Jun 1 2016 - May 31 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date functions in BO aren't quite as mature as they should be.

You can retrieve the value entered in the prompt, but it will be a string.  First, we'll need to convert it to a date type.  We'll call this variable `[End Date]`.

`=ToDate(UserResponse("Enter value for End Date:");"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a")`

This assumes that the prompt text is "Enter value for End Date:", and your local date format is "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").  Adjust as necessary.

Once you have that, it's a relatively simple calculation of subtracting the day of the month from the date:

`=LastDayOfMonth(RelativeDate([End Date];-DayNumberOfMonth([End Date])))`

Finally, you can filter the chart to show dates less than this.

**Edit to add filtering logic**

To use the above in a filter, you will need another variable to determine whether or not a row should be displayed.  Assuming the chart's displayed date comes from an object named `[Date]`, you could do the following:

`=If [Date] < LastDayOfMonth(RelativeDate([End Date];-DayNumberOfMonth([End Date]))) Then 'Y' Else 'N'`

Create this as a variable named `[DisplayDate]`, then simply apply a filter to the chart with `[DisplayDate] = 'Y'`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I got the both variables working but I cant seem to get the filter to work. I may be doing it wrong as I've never filtered on a chart before.